# Move a div to the start of his parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm making a slider, everything is good except for the previous button.
Here is my start:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div id="1" class="slider">
            <button class="full prevSlide">-</button> 
            <button class="full nextSlide">+</button>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="slider">
            <button class="full prevSlide">-</button> 
            <button class="full nextSlide">+</button>
    </div>
<div id="3" class="slider">
            <button class="full prevSlide">-</button> 
            <button class="full nextSlide">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I click on the + button for the first time, the #1 move after the #3 with this code:

```
function showNextSlide(el) {
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).children("div.slider:first").fadeOut()
     .next('div.slider').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo(this);
    });
}
```

But how to move #1 before #2 when I click on the - button?
Here is my code for the prev button:

```
function showPrevSlide(el) {
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).children("div.slider:first").fadeOut();
        $(this).children('div.slider:last').fadeIn();
        $(this).prepend(this);
    });
}
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3js4b4/1/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like this

```
var index = 0;
$(".slider:not(:first)").hide();
$(".nextSlide").click(function() {
    $(".slider").hide();
    index++;
    index = index % $(".slider").length;
    $(".slider").eq(index).show();
});
$(".prevSlide").click(function() {
    $(".slider").hide();
    index--;
    index = index % $(".slider").length;
    $(".slider").eq(index).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4fj32c6/6/)

***Edit***

```
var index = 0;
$(".slider:not(:first)").hide();
$(".nextSlide").click(function() {
    var slider=$(this).closest(".slideshow").find(".slider")
    slider.fadeOut();
    index++;
    index = index % slider.length;
    slider.eq(index).fadeIn();
});
$(".prevSlide").click(function() {
    var slider=$(this).closest(".slideshow").find(".slider")
    slider.fadeOut();
    index--;
    index = index % slider.length;
    slider.eq(index).fadeIn();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4fj32c6/7/)

Comment: I can't because multiple sliders are on the page

Comment: SO what? What makes it impossible?

Comment: Thanks for your time; I've find another solution to move the div

Comment: @Meezy atleast upvote the answer for the effort put towards solving your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function showPrevSlide(el) {
        el.each(function(){
            $(this).children("div.slider:first").fadeOut();
            $(this).children('div.slider:last').fadeIn();
            $(this).prepend($(this).children('div.slider:last'));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3js4b4/4/

what did i change:
1st of all, you do need the prev next buttons only once - just put them below your slideshow markup

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide"></div> 
    ... and so on
</div>
<button class="full prevSlide">-</button> 
<button class="full nextSlide">+</button>
```

then i simplified your function. with your solution, of having the active slide always at position one of the slider list, you don't need to pass any elements with it.

```
function showNextSlide() {
    $('.slideshow > .slider:first').fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.slideshow');
}
```

for the previous button, you would do it like that:

```
function showPrevSlide() {
    $('.slideshow > .slider:first').fadeOut(1000);
     $('.slideshow > .slider:last')
     .fadeIn(1000)
     .prependTo('.slideshow');
}
```

with this solution, your slides are a little bit jumpy though - since we don't have any css styling but a crossover effect, the new slide will open below the old slide and after the old slide has finished fading out, it will jump on top.

i usually solve this with a position: absolute for the slides. but then you also have to position your prev/next buttons manually... this would restrict you to a certain size for your slides - or you would have to get the slide size via js and reposition your buttons...